# Is there a way to start a process with a remote working directory?

Tags: cmd

I'm trying to run an installer of a network drive which seems to want you to start it from its own directory as the working directory and I don't want to do push/pop(the installer launches the msi install then quits making it hard to recycle the push with pop). Is there a way to do this from cmd.exe without adding the extra layer of powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cmd /c "pushd \\servername\share\ & appToStart.exe"
```

Comment: yes I understand but I don't want to do push as it changes state potentially leading to running out of drives(I'm fine with temporarily changing state but then I have to figure out when to call pop as the command launches another process)

Comment: It turns out there was session functionality to run multiple commands and I ended up doing push/pop.